# Adding time to a date with Scapy / Python?

Tags: python, datetime, scapy

I am working on a DNS packet sniffer using python and scapy. I need to be able to look at a window of time by looking at timestamps on DNS packets.

I have parsed my scapy timestamp into an appropriate python time format, but am struggling with adding time to it. Specifically, how can I add a period of time (say, 20 seconds) to my timestamp?

For reference, this is how I am trying to do this now:

```
starting_time_window = a
domain_to_check = b

formatted_time = datetime.strptime(starting_time_window, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The value of formatted_time when printed to the console is:

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 17, 38, 40, 807326)
```

I have tried adding time by doing the following, but it does not work:

`ending_time_window = formatted_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)`

Comment: Since we dont know what's the input variable...  what is the current output of your code?

Comment: Updated my question to include that information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by changing my import statement from:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

to:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

I also changed:

```
ending_time_window = formatted_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)
```

to:

```
ending_time_window = formatted_time + timedelta(seconds=20)
```